# How to get the value for the particular user from the anchor tag in django view?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('vendors/', views.loomerang_admin_vendors, name="loomerang_admin_vendors"),
     path('vendor_profile/<str:userid>', views.loomerang_admin_vendor_profile, name="loomerang_admin_vendor_profile"),
]
```

template

```
{% for vendor in vendors %} 
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">{{vendor.id}}</th>
      <td>{{vendor.date_joined|date:"d-m-Y"}}</td>
      <td name="vendor_id"><a href="{% url 'loomgerang_admin:loom_admin_vendor_profile' userid %}">{{vendor.userid}}</a></td>
      <td>{{vendor.first_name}}</td>
      <td>{{vendor.status}}</td>
      <td>20-12-2021</td>
      <td>Lokesh</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
def loomerang_admin_vendor_profile(request, userid):
    print(request.user.userid)
    vendor_name = request.POST.get("vendor_id")
    basic_details = CustomUser.objects.filter(id=request.user.id)
    store_details = basic_details[0].vendor_details.all()
    print(store_details)
    return render(request, 'loom_admin/vendor_profile.html', {'basic_details':basic_details, 'store_details':store_details})
```

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    mobile_number = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    customer = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False)
    vendor = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=True)
    userid = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=True)
    approved_by = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    approved_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default="Waiting")
    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.userid)
```

I have shown all the details of the users as a table. If I click the Id in one row, It will redirect me to another page and get all the information the particular user has. Here I am don't know to do that. please, expecting an answer.

Comment: Can you share your `CustomUser` model? Is this the user model?

Comment: yes. that is the user model.

Comment: Why is there an `id` and a `userid` (that can be NULL)?

Comment: sorry. Id field mistakenly I added. I have created userid for different users using save method in models. now, I remove that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first of all have to filter by the argument userid pass to request and then you get the id through forloop in template like  vendor.userid, i don't know what you are trying to accomplish by getting the vendor_name = request.POST.get("vendor_id"), do you have a different model for vendor ?

```
def loomerang_admin_vendor_profile(request, userid):
    print(request.user.userid)
    vendor_name = request.POST.get("vendor_id")
    basic_details = CustomUser.objects.filter(id=userid)
    store_details = basic_details[0].vendor_details.all()
    print(store_details)
    return render(request, 'loom_admin/vendor_profile.html', {'basic_details':basic_details, 'store_details':store_details})
```

```
{% for vendor in vendors %} 
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">{{vendor.id}}</th>
      <td>{{vendor.date_joined|date:"d-m-Y"}}</td>
      <td name="vendor_id"><a href="{% url 'loomgerang_admin:loom_admin_vendor_profile' vendor.userid %}">{{vendor.userid}}</a></td>
      <td>{{vendor.first_name}}</td>
      <td>{{vendor.status}}</td>
      <td>20-12-2021</td>
      <td>Lokesh</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your answer. Here, I am taking Id for changing one boolean flag in the model. my mistake was not passing the vendor.id into the template in for loop. I solved that.